# Ошибка при установке MySQL через консоль

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd

Использую команду для установки:

```
msiexec /i " mysql-5.5.23-winx64.msi"  INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL" /L* "C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-log.txt"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте указать полный путь к файлу msi или перейти в его директрию через `cd [path]`

Comment: И пробел как первый символ имени пакета - слегка сомнителен...

Comment: @matrix Сделал так  `cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64 && msiexec /i mysql-5.5.23-winx64.msi /quiet INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL"` , но теперь не устанавливает не в указанную директорию

Comment: @Идентикон А зачем у вас msi лежит в Syswow64?

Comment: @matrix Туда по умолчанию скачивается, проблему решил оказалось надо `/quiet` после `INSTALLDIR` ставить.

Answer (score 0):

`cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64 && msiexec /i mysql-5.5.23-winx64.msi INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL" /quiet`